# Can't boot windows 7 from SSD

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, multi-boot, mbr

I had windows 7 installed on my primary HD. Then I got an SSD and did a fresh installation on it. Somehow I messed up the second installation (on the SSD) and now to boot into it, I must boot into the first one (on the HD), where I get a menu screen of "select which OS to boot".

Disconnecting the first HD gives me "no operating system found" error message when booting into the SSD.

How can I fix it? I want to be able to boot into the SSD OS without menus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disconnect the old HDD (optional but recommended), insert your Win7 Installation media and boot on it. Click `Repair your computer`, then select your SSD Windows installation and then `Next`, then at the System Recovery Options menu click `Command Prompt`.

At the Command Prompt enter:

`bootrec /fixmbr` - Writes the Master Boot Record
`bootrec /fixboot` - Writes a new boot sector onto the system partition

Of course, you can always skip all the command line stuff, at the System Recovery Options menu, just select `Startup Repair` and let it do it's thing.

Remember that in your computers BIOS you will need to change the boot device order so the SSD is the first device in the list.